# How old is too old? (Tor Versions)

Tags: orbot, update

Some apps (specifically Orbot) do not update with newer versions of Tor, at least not right away. (Orbot is still at 0.2.7.5)

What is the oldest "safe" version of Tor, or, does it really matter that much if my Tor is slightly outdated?

Comment: https://consensus-health.torproject.org/#recommendedversions some of these have quite bad bugs though, like 0.2.8.6 and the [`ReachableAddresses` bug](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19973)